# "setprecision()" and floating point

Tags: c++

I'm trying to Run a program that converts Currency From KD to DOLLAR and EURO.

The problem is I'm expecting the output to be with 3 floating numbers but the actual out put is just 1 floating number after the decimal point like the pi.

[image]

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Don't post code as images, but as properly formatted text.

Comment: I tried to paste your code into my IDE, but it doesn't like pictures.  No posted code as text == no help.

Answer (score 1):

[std::fixed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) should solve your issue :

```
double a = 3.149;

std::cout <<  std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed << a << "\n";
```

will output :

> 3.149000